# UIMA RUTA is not annotating text after "<!"

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I am using UIMA RUTA to annotate wide range of documents. They come from different sources and sometimes happens that the combination of characters <! is present in the middle of the document. The text after <! is annotated as MARKUP and ignored by other annotations.

Is there an option to turn of this behavior?
Even if I switch off the MARKUP annotations, the text after <! is not being annotated by any other annotations.

I found the part of code that is responsible for creating most of the MARKUP annotations (DefaultSeeder in org.apache.uima.ruta.seed package), but I am not able to find which part of code is responsible for MARKUP annotations starting with <!

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What do you mean by "Even if I switch off the MARKUP annotations"? Did you update the internal indexing?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. Most likely, you want to configure the RutaEngine to use a different seeder, i.e. the TextSeeder instead of the DefaultSeeder. The TextSeeder does not create MARKUP annotations.

You can also change the visibility settings so that text covered by MARKUP annotations is processed normally, e.g., with ADDRETAINTYPE(MARKUP);

Comment: Thank you Peter, it seems that the problem I am facing is little deeper in code. First by "switch off the MARKUP" I meant that I tried to replace "case 15" in SeedLexer.java - in the switch at the end of the file... This removed the MARKUP but still in those blocks which used to be MARKUPs is not forming any other annotation.

Comment: EXAMPLE: 
Text text text <! some more text, and even some more... > text text.

The text after "<!" has absolutely no annotation (SW, SPACE, COMMA...) nothing... Till it finds ">".

I tried all that RETAINTYPE stuff but it seem that "<!" is creating some kind of super MARKUPs that are not annotable.

Comment: Ah ok, I will take a closer look

Comment: You should not directly adapt the generated lexer code, rather the jflex grammar of the lexer and regenerate the class. I assume your problems are caused by a bug in the TextLexer, which still creates MARKUP annotations (I will fix it). As a workaround, can you build on other annotations than ANY within the <! … >?